# LED Matrix Calculation

Tags: led, calculation

I am new to electrical engineering and want to build an LED 4x4 cube. The schematic is below. I need to know how much power I need if all LEDs are on at once. The LEDs I use use an average of 2.8V and 20mA. What power supply do I need? My result was ≈12V and ≈100mA. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: You need to add resistors to set the current to 20mA for 12v.

Comment: Don't you only need 12 LEDs to build a cube?

Comment: @Andyaka I was thinking it should be 64 LEDs (4 x 4 x 4).

Comment: Anyone else care to me an informed guess?

Comment: Cube has 12 ribs.

Comment: Yes for the whole cube I would need 64 LEDs but first I want to test everything on a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding. I now added a 600ohm resistor before every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your calculation is correct: 4 * 2.8V = 11.2V and 4 * 20mA = 80mA (so 100 mA should be enough).

Now there are important things to consider: Each series should have a current regulator. The most simple a series resistor. Some constant current regulators exist but it depends on the budget and cost. For only 20mA it's not necessary unless you need high end quality and an exact light intensity and so on.

The best way to help with regulation, is to lower the voltage a little bit so that less current flows through the LED series. But that's only possible with adjustable supplies. The resistors will also reduce the current (and the voltage).
If you can use it with less light than it would give with 20 mA, I recommend using resistor so that it uses +- 15 mA.
There will be less risk of imbalance.

It's also important that all the LED be the same, bought at the same time in the same batch.

Answer (score 1):

Not all LEDs have same drop voltage at same current because of technological differences. Parallel connection of discrete LEDs not advised. Resistors in series, one of each chain, should be applied. And in common, LED are fed by current, not voltage, resistors define current.